# A generalization of the edge isoperimetry problem for the hypercube

Tags: coding-theory, extremal-combinatorics

For any $n$, and any $1 \leq k  \leq 2^n$, and any $1 \leq q \leq n-1$, we want $k$ binary vectors of length $n$, organized in a matrix $M$ with $k$ rows and $n$ columns, that will minimize $p(M,q)$ over all binary matrices $M$ on $k$ distinct rows and $n$ columns, where $p(M,q)$ is the sum, over all $n \choose q$ choices of $q$ columns, of the number of vectors in the projection of those columns. For example, for $M$ being
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
we get $p(M,2)=8$ since choosing the first two columns we have 2 distinct rows in the projection, whereas the other two choices of two columns gives 3 distinct rows each.
When $q=n-1$ this minimization question is equivalent to asking for the induced subgraph on $k$ vertices of the hypercube of dimension $n$ having the maximum number of edges, since $p(M,n-1)$ is $k$ times $n$   minus the number of edges in the subgraph induced by the nodes corresponding to the rows of $M$ (as the dimension this edge crosses, when that column is left out, we get two identical rows). This has been shown (Sergiu Hart, A note on the edges of the hypercube, Discrete Math. 1976) to be achieved by the $k$ vectors corresponding to the binary representation of the k numbers from 0 to $k-1$, with leading 0s to give them length $n$. His result implies that the matrix $M$ with these vectors as rows will achieve the minimum value of $p(M,q)$ for any $q$ between $\lceil \log_2 k\rceil-1$ and $n-1$, and it is easy to show that it also achieves the minimum value of $p(M,1)$.
 But what about $q=2$, or any other $q$ smaller than $\log_2 k -1$?
 Do we know that the same set of vectors will again achieve the minimum, over all binary $M$ on $k$ distinct rows and $n$ columns? Or maybe simpler, do we know it if $k$ is a power of 2?

Comment: What does "the projection of those columns" mean? What does it mean to have "rows in the projection"? Based on the numbers you give for $p(M,2)=8$, it sounds like you're talking about the number of $0$s that appear, but I'm not sure since I don't see how that's relates to the interpretation as "the number of vectors" in a "projection" of the columns.

Comment: The projection of the first two columns on M in the above gives the three rows 00,11,11, and this contains only two distinct rows/vectors, namely 00 and 11. For the other two choices of two columns you get three distinct vectors, namely 00, 10 and 11, and thus p(M,2)=2+3+3=8.

Comment: Related, but I don't have any deep knowledge on this topic. Harper's Theorem is relevant: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0097316519301670

Comment: @kodlu Harper’s Theorem relates to the (closed) neighborhood of some k nodes of the hypercube, but the problem we are facing relates only to the k nodes themselves, and projections along certain indices, so I do not see the connection.